# How to read "Manufacturer Device Name" and other information from an EtherCAT slave device using TwinCAT 3 programmatically in C#

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads-.net

I've tried to read the information of an EtherCAT slave device from ADS server with `TcAdsClient.ReadAny()` method but couldn't. Below is the prototype of the method. I don't know what to use for `indexGroup` and `indexOffset` for "Manufacturer Device Name" at index `0x1008` (see attached image). Any suggestion to point me into the right direction would be appreciate.

```cs
public Object ReadAny(
    uint indexGroup,
    uint indexOffset,
    Type type
)
```

[image: Manufacturer Device Name information]

Best,

Hoai

I don't know if this is the right way to get that information or not but I could communicate to the EtherCAT slave and access its read/write registers in "Config Mode" without any issue using ADS .NET interface as described above. I don't want to use PLC program because I don't want to get into "Run Mode" with TwinCAT.

Comment: i think it is not possible, what you can do it try to use the automation interface api from beckhoff, it allows you to automate tasks inside the GUI https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tc3_automationinterface/242682763.html&id=